# Pattern matching case classes, all cases have same return

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class, scala-3

I'm new to Scala and the only way I saw people access case classes was with pattern matching.

I recently solved a Huffman coding problem with the following code

```scala
  abstract class TreeNodes 
  case class Leaf(weight: Int, value: String) extends TreeNodes
  case class Node(weights: Int, left: TreeNodes, right: TreeNodes) extends TreeNodes

  // P50
  def huffman(freq: List[(String,Int)]): List[(String,String)] = {
    def makeNode(left: TreeNodes, right: TreeNodes): Node = 
      (left,right) match 
        case (Leaf(w1,_),Leaf(w2,_)) => Node(w1 + w2, left,right)
        case (Node(w1,_,_),Leaf(w2,_)) => Node(w1 + w2, left ,right)
        case (Leaf(w1,_), Node(w2,_,_)) => Node(w1 + w2, left, right)
        case (Node(w1,_,_), Node(w2,_,_)) => Node(w1 + w2, left, right)

    def makeLeaves(freq: List[(String,Int)]): List[TreeNodes] = freq.map((s: String, i: Int) => Leaf(i,s))

    def makeTree(nodes: List[TreeNodes]): List[TreeNodes] = {
      if nodes.size == 1 then nodes else {
        val sortedNodes = nodes.sortBy(_ match {case Leaf(w,_) => w; case Node(w,_,_) => w})
        makeTree(sortedNodes.appended(makeNode(sortedNodes.head,sortedNodes.tail.head)).drop(2))
      }
    }

    def traverseTree(node: TreeNodes, acc: String): List[(String, String)] = {
      node match  
        case Leaf(w, s) => List((s,acc))
        case Node(w, left, right) => traverseTree(left, acc + "0") ::: traverseTree(right, acc + "1")
    }
    traverseTree(makeTree(makeLeaves(freq)).head, "").sortBy(_._1)
  }
```

where the input and output should be like so:

```
scala> huffman(List(("a", 45), ("b", 13), ("c", 12), ("d", 16), ("e", 9), ("f", 5)))
res0: List[String, String] = List((a,0), (b,101), (c,100), (d,111), (e,1101), (f,1100))
```

The code is correct and produces the desired output. However, I want to refactor the `makeNode` function to a cleaner version, since all cases have the same return.

I want a more concise version.
Is there a way to create a common field for different case classes or any other way to access case classes without pattern matching?

Comment: Just declare `def weight: Int` in the shared base class, the values of the case classes will automatically implement that method: `abstract class TreeNode { def weight: Int }`, `def makeNode(left: TreeNode, right: TreeNode) = Node(left.weight + right.weight, left, right)`. Also, you probably want to have it `sealed`.

Comment: `def weight: Int` worked perfectly, please write it as an answer so I can mark the question as solved. I still have a few more questions. Why can't I do `TreeNodes(weight: Int)` and rewrite both case classes as `... extends TreeNodes(weight)` and treat weight as a val of both `Leaf` and `Node`? Why does it have to be a `def`? If this file exists as a standalone (not going to extend it from another file), should I still use `sealed`?

Comment: Found the answer to my first question, the problem was that I used the same name `weight` for both the abstract constructor and the case classes constructors. I renamed both case classes constructora to `weights` and passed them like so: `... extends TreeNodes(weights)`. I am still confused by the `sealed` though

Comment: No you don't have to use `sealed` in that case, but using it is a best practice for an additional benefit: the compiler is able to pick up all the possible cases and warn you when your pattern match is not exhaustive.

Comment: I see, it immediately raises a warning on the match. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare the common methods in the common interface, in this case, add `def weight: Int` or `val weight: Int` to the base class.

In Scala 2.x:

```
sealed abstract class TreeNodes {
  def weight: Int
}
case class Leaf(weight: Int, value: String) extends TreeNodes
case class Node(weight: Int, left: TreeNodes, right: TreeNodes) extends TreeNodes

//...

  def makeNode(left: TreeNodes, right: TreeNodes): Node =
    Node(left.weight + right.weight, left,right)
```

In Scala 3.x:

```
enum TreeNodes:
  case Leaf(weight: Int, value: String)
  case Node(weight: Int, left: TreeNodes, right: TreeNodes)
  def weight: Int
```

but remember to import the `Leaf` and `Node` if you want that the rest of the code works as-is: `import TreeNodes._`.